# How to initialize the custom Widget in kindo grid TD(grid cell)?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery Custom widget, how to initialize  that widget in Kendo Grid cell using the template?

This is my Template

```
<script id="IDCOL-tmpl" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">

            <div class="IDCOL">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.IDCOL').Block();
                {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
            </div>

    </script>
```

and Kendo Grid initialization

```
$("#container").kendoGrid({
    ..........
    columns : [{
        title : "ID",
        template : kendo.template($("#IDCOL-tmpl").html())
    }, "StartTime", "EndTime"]
});
```

This is the error:

> "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.") in globalEval (which is in jquery-1.7.1.js)

Comment: Why does this not work for you? Please prove as much detail as possible about what you have, and what you want to have when asking a question.

Comment: it showing an error("Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.") in globalEval(which is in jquery-1.7.1.js)